# Using Python re.Search() to Find Unallowable Characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use Python re to test a string for anything other than numbers and dashes. So only strings like this would pass: "1-2-3-4"

Problem is, it says a string "1-0-0-0" contains unallowables. It seems to return True no matter what I throw at it. "asdf", "asdf%", "1-0-0-0" all return True. I've never been really good with regex.

Can anyone identify what's wrong with my pattern?

```
def checkStringForUnallowables(test):
    # Returns False if the string passes the unallowables check
    stringCheck = re.compile('[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')

    # Pass the string in search function of RE object (string_check):
    if(stringCheck.search(test) == None):
        print("String does not contain unallowables - returning False")
        return False
    else:
        print("String contains unallowables - returning True")
        return True
```

Comment: To match a string like `1-2-3`... you need a `stringCheck = re.compile(r'^\d+(?:-\d+)*', test)`. To match any char but a digit and `-`, you may use `[^-0-9]`

Comment: *anything other than numbers and dashes* so make your life simple with `[^\d-]`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the if condition

```
import re

def checkStringForUnallowables(test):
    stringCheck = re.compile('[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')

    if not stringCheck.search(test):
        print("String does not contain unallowables - returning False")
        return False
    else:
        print("String contains unallowables - returning True")
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the regex string to [^\d-] ended up working.